# How do I exit or cancel inline commands in the terminal?

Tags: mysql, terminal

If I'm in the Terminal and I want to exit or cancel a command how would I do so? Escape does nothing and hitting the up arrow copies the command.

[image]

Comment: ctrl-c should do it

Comment: That's the MySQL CLI, not bash.

Comment: If you need to kill the statement that's running you might need to use `SHOW PROCESSLIST` and `KILL` from another MySQL connection on the same server.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> is used to kill a process with the signal `SIGINT`, and can be intercepted by a program so it can clean its self up before exiting, or not exit at all.

<kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd> is used for suspending a process by sending it the signal `SIGSTOP`, which cannot be intercepted by the program.

**Random fact:**

If you were writing a long command such as `$ cd /User/myname/Desktop -r grep | .*.*` and want to delete it press <kbd>Ctrl + U</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Type `\c` and hit return. That will clear the current input statement.

Comment: This does not always work. Sometimes commands/process get stuck in infinite loops and won't respond.